# React build shows white page with Django

Tags: reactjs, django, build, create-react-app

I am trying to load React build files in a Django template (serving the React build files via Django static files). I’ve had success using this approach in the past with other Django templates, but with this particular case, the React app is not attaching to my div in the Django template. The React app is created using create_react_app with minimal changes.

My src/index.js file: (only changed the root element)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('chat-root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

My public/index.html file: (only changed the root element)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="chat-root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I built my files via npm run build and placed the build files in my Django static folder. These are then included in my Django template as follows. Note that this Django app has several other React “apps” that use this same approach without issue.

```
<div id="chat-root"></div>

{% compress js %}
<script src="{% static 'react/build_files/chat.chunk.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'react/build_files/main.chat.chunk.js' %}"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

The Django url setup works with a simple html template so I am sure that is correct.

I have also tried not setting **homepage** in package.json and setting "homepage": "/"
but that didn't help.

There are no error during build or on browser console. The network tab in dev tools shows that the scripts get loaded but no react components get created.

I am new to react so any help will be  appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing a similar issue, I was able to resolve it by placing **all** JS files created in the build.

I noticed there was another file **runtime~main.[number].js** being created when a build was created. I had skipped this file earlier based on the how the other React "apps" were added to static folder in Django app.

Placing this build file along with the other JS files allowed the app to attach to Django and load properly.